# Headphone jack changes and pauses songs

Tags: share

I shake my iphone headphone jack and it changes the song on my nano iPod 7th gen and I move it in circles and it also changes the song or pauses it I take out lint get still does it I don't understand is it programmed to act this way I use any other headphones doesnt act the same way I've already used two iPhone head phones still does it if the headphones aren't Apple related it won't do it

Comment: Hello. Your question is off-topic and will likely be closed soon. I recommend that you complete our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read our [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to understand what is on-topic for this site.

Comment: No I tried two iPhone headphones and it does the same if it's not Apple related it won't do it

Comment: It is still off-topic.

Comment: Turns out the mic controller thing does work

Comment: I'm confused is it the ipod?

Comment: And the headphones work good with other phones and stuff

Answer (score -2):

Are your headphones the kind with a build in mic/controller? I had a similar issue happen to me with my iPhone recently - it was to do with a poor connection or fraying *within* the headphones themselves. After trying a new set, the problem stopped. If as you say it only happens with one set of headphones - the issue is likely the headphones, rather than the iPod/iPhone.

Check also that the headphones you have are designed for use with Apple devices - it seems a bit much, but recently with more functionality being allowed via a simple interface, different manufacturers (ie: Samsung/Apple) have different standards for how they treat different events from this controller.

Finally - note that this is a community site for developers - aspiring and professional alike (I fall into the former at the moment!). your question perhaps may be better suited to the Apple website forums, rather than here. Hope this helps all the same.